# Can I flash hoodloader2 or HEX files on Arduino Simulators?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo

I want to make a HID Keyboard out of Arduino UNO, in UNO board the script runs perfectly fine, but the UNO board requires me to flash it every-time I want to put in a new script in it, so can I do the same on an Arduino Simulator? can I Flash Hoodloader2 on Arduino simulators by shorting the ICSP pins on UNO Board on a Simulator? if yes, please suggest the name of the application/ website.

Comment: which simulator?  ... why don't you just test it instead of asking?

Answer (score 0):

Only Arduino boards with ATmega16u2 as USB adapter can use Hoodloader. So not even all Uno clones can use it.

I doubt the simulator is so precise that it would simulate the second MCU on Uno to allow flashing it over its ICSP heeader (ICSP2). I guess it doesn't even support flashing the main MCU over ICSP.

If the simulator supports Arduino Lenonardo, then you can maybe use the HID library. Leonardo has ATmega32u4 which has native USB support.